# 'Invalid object name' using Dapper

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I am trying to use Dapper for my SQL query in C#.

I tried to build my code based on this article:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5275840/Dynamic-Query-Builder-for-Dapper

When running my code it stops at

```
var products =
```

and I get the following error message:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo_tbl_ProcessFlow'

I already used the same query in MS Access, so it should be ok.

So what am I doing wrong? I would expect a DataTable *(?)* as output.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Dapper;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

private void myVoid(string ServerName, string DatabaseName, string Batchnumber)
{
    var dynamicParams = new DynamicParameters();
            
    string sql = "SELECT TOP 10000 dbo_tbl_SmileData.BatchNumber, dbo_tbl_SmileData.DeviceName, dbo_tbl_SmileData_Data.Data_Value, dbo_tbl_SmileData.EvalDateStamp";
    sql += " FROM ((((dbo_tbl_ProcessFlow INNER JOIN dbo_tbl_SmileData ON dbo_tbl_ProcessFlow.ProcessFlow_ID = dbo_tbl_SmileData.ProcessFlow_ID) INNER JOIN dbo_tbl_SmileData_Data ON dbo_tbl_SmileData.SmileData_Id = dbo_tbl_SmileData_Data.SmileData_ID) INNER JOIN dbo_tbl_Data_List ON dbo_tbl_SmileData_Data.Data_List_Id = dbo_tbl_Data_List.Data_List_Id) INNER JOIN dbo_tbl_ProductProfile ON dbo_tbl_SmileData.ProductProfile_ID = dbo_tbl_ProductProfile.ProductProfile_ID) INNER JOIN dbo_tbl_Products ON dbo_tbl_ProductProfile.Product_ID = dbo_tbl_Products.Product_ID";
    sql += " WHERE (((dbo_tbl_SmileData.BatchNumber) Like @Batchnumber) AND ((dbo_tbl_SmileData_Data.Data_List_Id)=122) AND ((dbo_tbl_Data_List.Data_List_Id)=[dbo_tbl_SmileData_Data].[Data_List_Id]) AND ((dbo_tbl_ProcessFlow.ProcessFlow_ID)=[dbo_tbl_SmileData].[ProcessFlow_ID]) AND ((dbo_tbl_SmileData.SmileData_Id)=[dbo_tbl_SmileData_Data].[SmileData_ID]) AND ((dbo_tbl_ProductProfile.ProductProfile_ID)=[dbo_tbl_SmileData].[ProductProfile_ID]) AND ((dbo_tbl_ProductProfile.Product_ID)=[dbo_tbl_Products].[Product_ID]));";
    dynamicParams.Add("Batchnumber", Batchnumber);
            
    string conString = "Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=" + DatabaseName + ";Data Source=" + ServerName;

    SqlConnection cn;
    
    cn = new SqlConnection(conString);
    
    cn.Open();
    var products = cn.Query(sql, dynamicParams);
    cn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Wild guess: `dbo.tbl_ProcessFlow`?

Comment: What could possible be wrong with it? Because in MS Access it causes no problem, so the name should be correct and be available

Comment: @Evolyzer: dbo is the schema and tbl_ProcessFlow the table name. I think that there is a naming convention in MS Access that imported sql-server tables are prefixed with `schemaname_` followed by the tablename, to ensure that it's unique in access(since in MS SQL-Server you can have multiple tables with the same name if the schema is different).

Comment: You seem to be querying SqlServer ("SqlConnection"). So what is the relation to MSAccess? Does that query work when you execute it directly in SSMS? Double check that the table is named `dbo_tbl_ProcessFlow` (with underscore) instead of `dbo.tbl_ProcessFlow` (with dot separating schema and table name). And of course the same for all other tables

Comment: I figured out that Access uses _[dbo_tbl_SmileData].[ProcessFlow_ID]_ if a Table/Column is used multiple times, but SQL can't handle the _[]_. Also Access uses _dbo_tbl_SmileData_, but SQL needs _dbo.tbl_SmileData_. So the query works now.

Comment: So _[dbo_tbl_SmileData].[ProcessFlow_ID]_ becomes _dbo.tbl_SmileData.ProcessFlow_ID_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that Access uses *[dbo_tbl_SmileData].[ProcessFlow_ID]* if a table/column is used multiple times, but SQL can't handle the *[ ]*. Also Access uses *dbo_tbl_SmileData*, but SQL needs *dbo.tbl_SmileData*.

So *[dbo_tbl_SmileData].[ProcessFlow_ID]* becomes *dbo.tbl_SmileData.ProcessFlow_ID*.